# Trouble with CLI and iOS simulator

Tags: titanium, ios-simulator, command-line-interface, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm moving to a new machine and want to start out fresh. I'm leaving Appcelerator Studio behind and want to go all CLI.

The project I'm working on is still on SDK 5.5.1.

When I try to build our app for the iPhone simulator it builds fine and launches the simulator but when it tries to start the app the simulator goes black execpt for the status bar. No errors are thrown in the terminal and nothing interesting shows up in console.app

I can launch the app in the simulator on my old machine without issues (done it 1000 times or so).

I build with: `appc run -p ios`

This is the last output I get:

```
[INFO]  Launching iOS Simulator
-- Start simulator log -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  Application started
[INFO]  OurAppName/2.8.1 (5.5.1.b18727f)
```

This is my setup:

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.5.1

2017-02-08 14:54:46

Name = Mac OS X

Xcode 8.1

Version = 10.12.3

Node.js Version = 4.7.3

npm Version = 2.15.11

Titanium CLI Version = 5.0.9

Titanium SDK Version = 5.5.1.GA

SDK Path = /Users/-/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA

Target Platform = iphone
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Somehow it started working while setting up my Android enviroment. I'm not sure why :/

Answer (score 1):

You could try building on a specific simulator

run

```
appc run -p iOS --device-id
```

it will prompt you with all the devices available and you can choose among the list (choose an iOS 9 simulator, it looks like the problem is with the iOS 10 simulator)

Comment: Might have worked - but it worked after I set the Android stuff up. Don't know why. Thanks for your input though 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but we're using Titanium SDK 5.4.0, and so far still using Xcode 7. For another project, using Titanium 6 we are using Xcode 8.

We experienced some issues in communication between Studio/CLI and Xcode/Simulator.

Comment: Thats why I'm running Xcode 8.1 instead of 8.2 which isn't supported by 5.5.1. 

But yeah it could have been the cause so thanks for the input 

Answer (score 0):

### if you are using Xcode 8.1 then you can use the following command

```
appc ti build -p ios -I 10.1
```

where `-p` is platform and `-I` is IOS version

### if you want to check IOS version

- Step 1: Go to `Xcode`
- Step 2: Window -> Devices.[image]

please see the image it will clear all things.

It worked for me.